# libGDX Google Play Services error

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services

I am new on libGDX and making my first game when I try to add Google Play services project doesn't build and shows an error.

I followed this tutorial

https://chandruscm.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/how-to-setup-google-play-game-services-in-libgdx-using-android-studio/

Andorid Studio shows me this error

Error: Execution failed for task ':BaseGameUtils: extractDebugAnnotations'.

> originalComplianceLevel